# UITableView setEditing does not allow me to delete a cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, swipe

After an edit button is clicked, I call setEditing like so:

```
[self.tableview setEditing:YES];
```

Then, the red delete buttons appear

[image]

These buttons are very difficult to interact with. Only while swiping ~35px to the right from the delete button does the big "Delete" option appear on the right side of the tableviewcell.

What I want to happen:

1. I tap (not swipe) the red minus button
2. The delete button appears on the right side of the cell
3. Only if I click that delete button does it actual delete

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the built in `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell`, the '-' button should allow taps to display the Delete button. You will have to handle the delete event in the delegate.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.data deleteEntryAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using a custom UITableViewCell which has a couple of accessory buttons involved.